# i want to save vue.js code Inside div in database

Tags: html, vuejs2

i want to save vue js code Inside div in database using mongo db
i create ws to save page Inside mongoDb using nodejs
when i click save button to save code vue js Inside html

```
save(){
  var vm=this;
  var page={
    "id":"2",
    "page":vm.$el.innerHTML
  }
  console.log("hh"+vm.$el.innerHTML);
  var HTTPpOST=axios.create({
  baseURL: `http://localhost:3000/api/product/2`,
  headers: {
   Accept:'application/json'

  }
})
HTTPpOST.put('',page).then(function(response){
}) .catch(function(error){
         var vm=this;
  console.log("error"+error);
 })
```

i only get html code without vue js code
how can i get both and save them bothin my databse?
this is html :

```
<div id="app" ref="foo">
      <ul>
        <li v-for="prod in products">
              <h1 style="color:red">{{prod.fields.name}}</h1>
              <p>{{prod.fields.description}}</p>
        </li>
      </ul>

        <button @click="save">save</button>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try prerendering using Nuxt.js or webpack with vue-server-renderer. Server side rendering helps you to get that elements expanded by Vue.js and you will be having fully rendered webpage.

Look at [Vue - Server Side Rendering](https://ssr.vuejs.org/en/)